# JSON Problem with Cross Domain..Alternative Parse out of iframe?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, iframe

I am taking a stab in the dark here.

I cannot do a cross domain request to get a piece of json data. I have tried this several ways but the cross domain policy keeps getting me. Is there a way I can do this by just parsing the data inside a hidden iframe? Is this possible using javascript?

http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.json is the json page

Comment: Have you checked if the API supports JSONP?  Is it an API or is it something you reverse engineered?

Comment: http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.json is the json data

Comment: There's no real easy way to do it in the frontend/javascript side. Most developers get around this by creating a proxy through backend code. Meaning, your PHP, Java, or .Net code makes the request to the API, and then your frontend can access the data from your own server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever *crossdomain policy* puts me up against the fence, I use a `PHP` proxy.

Use `PHP` to curl in the *file you want* and then it's *as good as yours*. When you hit the `PHP` file (which is on your server) there's no cross domain issues.

[Your PHP file will look like something like this.](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm) Now whenever you hit the `PHP` file, you'll see the file you curled, but it appears to be coming from **your domain**.

This is basically a **cheap trick** and should only be used when you have no control over the policies.

Here's the PHP code you will need:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.json');

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Awesome and exactly what I am looking for. Can you elaborate on how the code would work to get the contents of the page nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.json?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a great use case for this. You can basically just copy/paste the code I linked you and replace their URL with the JSON URL you're wanting to get. Once the new php file is on your server, go to the url for your php file and bam - you are now the NFL.

Comment: Do you have your pages up where I can take a look? If so, what are the URLs ?

Comment: allencoded.com/test.php is the one I am working with right now

Comment: I can see that your PHP is working (that's a good sign). I added an edit to my answer which is the exact php code you will need. Copy the code and paste it in over what you currently have and see if that does the trick.

Comment: That doesn't generate anything :( Just tried it and its still up if you want to look

Comment: @allencoded let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2445/discussion-between-jackson-and-allencoded)